# Basic algebra: linear equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$0 = \frac{1}{6}(-X) + \frac{5}{6}(7.5) \implies X = 5 \times 7.5 = 37.5.$$

I cannot see how you get X = 5 x 7.5 in the equation above; could someone make the steps to this conclusion explicit for me?

Comment: Multiply both sides by $6$ and move $-X$ to the LHS.

Comment: They multiplied both sides by the denominator to remove it, moved $X$ to the right side and read the result from right to left, that's all.

Comment: $0 = \frac{1}{6}(-X)+\frac{5}{6}(7.5) \iff 0=\frac{-X}{6}+\frac{5\cdot7.5}{6}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$0=\dfrac16(-X)+\dfrac56(7.5).$$

Multiply both sides by $6$:

$$0=-X+5\times7.5.$$

Add $X$ to both sides:

$$X=5\times7.5.$$